# Container process on host machine

Tags: process, docker

I'm using Docker and would like to identify which processes are running on containers.
So, I run this command on my container, which will uses nearly 100 % CPU.

```
md5sum /dev/urandom
```

After that I've checked processes using `htop` on host machine.

[image]

How can I identify, that this command is running inside a container instead of host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Docker Processes Shown on Host Process List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26763450/6309)", you can also  run `top` then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and select the `nsPID` and `nsUSER`

The nsPID should match `docker inspect --format='{{ .State.Pid }}' <acontainer>`
(as [in this example](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/blob/2ef9cc6a1c8c8b06c299b959b5d35ab6b7cc6ab9/bin/docker-ns#L16-L26), inspired by the [pipework script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pjkundert/pipework/master/pipework))

Comment: I see number like this under `nsPID`: `4026532234`
It is different from host process numbers, but where this number comes from?

Comment: " It is different from host process numbers" yes, it is not an host process id (different namespace), but you should find the same number when inspecting a container.

Comment: That is okay, but should I manually inspect all the containers looking after this number?

Comment: @mum007 that is the idea (should be made into a script)

Comment: Now I have only 1 container, so I try to use `inspect` to find this number. Which row should contains it?

Comment: @mum007 what output do you get?

Comment: @mum007 `docker inspect --format='{{ .State.Pid }}' <acontainer>` should only give you one value, in your case: 5464

Comment: @mum007 that doesn't match the nsPID, but should match one of your processes, as shown in http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216619/7490 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26763450/6309

Comment: Thanks for this easy solution!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add the `cgroup` column which identifies the container the process is running under.

- Press <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Setup
- Columns
- Choose `CGROUP`
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save

Comment: Under cgroup: `system.sli` What does it mean?

Comment: That sounds like the start to `system.slice/something`.  Your column is probably too narrow to see the entire thing.  It may be something like `system.slice/docker-462783dd81f9515dc2a9adf9c2e767559c3d2dbe6a38e45e705d144000f61362.scope` which would be a docker `cgroup`, or it could be `system.slice/NetworkManager.service` which is not.

Comment: Is there any method to see all the columns in max width and first of all to save column settings. After `Ctrl+C` everything is default.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to run a command on the container:

```
docker exec <container> ps ax
```

This should list the processes running in the container.

[Docker Exec Reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/)