# gunicorn spawn workers in host and container as well

Tags: docker, gunicorn, fastapi

I'm trying to deploy an api with `fastapi` with docker on a server with `nginx` as a reversed proxy.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.6

RUN mkdir /srv/app

ENV SEGPKG=/srv/app
COPY . $SEGPKG
WORKDIR /srv/app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip --proxy my_proxy --trusted-host pypi.python.org

RUN pip install -e $SEGPKG --proxy my_proxy

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["gunicorn","--timeout","90","--log-level","error", "--reload", "-b", "0.0.0.0:80","--worker-class=uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker", "--workers=24", "app.main:app"]
```

and everything is handled by a `docker-compose`. Nginx is already installed on my server.
The deployment is ok: i can access my api, make a request and recieve a response.

By chanche yesterday, I ran `top` on my linux centos server and i saw this:

```
  3369 root      20   0  582388 338624   6016 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.62 gunicorn
  3389 root      20   0  582388 338460   5792 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.40 gunicorn
  3382 root      20   0  582388 338428   5800 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.45 gunicorn
  3356 root      20   0  582392 338408   5788 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.24 gunicorn
  3355 root      20   0  582392 338400   5788 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.86 gunicorn
  3424 root      20   0  582392 338388   5792 S   0.3  1.0   0:45.80 gunicorn
  3344 root      20   0  582392 338384   5796 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.26 gunicorn
  3413 root      20   0  582392 338384   5788 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.52 gunicorn
  3341 root      20   0  582404 338376   5836 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.10 gunicorn
  3348 root      20   0  582392 338372   5792 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.38 gunicorn
  3402 root      20   0  582392 338360   5788 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.15 gunicorn
  3401 root      20   0  582392 338344   5796 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.24 gunicorn
  3422 root      20   0  582392 338344   5788 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.75 gunicorn
  3351 root      20   0  582392 338336   5788 S   1.0  1.0   0:46.47 gunicorn
  3359 root      20   0  582392 338316   5788 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.48 gunicorn
  3399 root      20   0  582388 338312   5788 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.01 gunicorn
  3408 root      20   0  582392 338312   5788 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.38 gunicorn
  3421 root      20   0  582392 338312   5788 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.08 gunicorn
  3343 root      20   0  582396 338304   5812 S   0.7  1.0   0:45.97 gunicorn
  3360 root      20   0  582392 338296   5788 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.43 gunicorn
  3397 root      20   0  582388 338288   5788 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.49 gunicorn
  3425 root      20   0  582392 338260   5792 S   0.3  1.0   0:46.42 gunicorn
  3345 root      20   0  582392 338204   5792 S   0.7  1.0   0:45.63 gunicorn
  3353 root      20   0  582392 338160   5788 S   0.7  1.0   0:46.59 gunicorn
```

Then i went to the docker container created for serving this api and ran `top`

```
 1 root      20   0   36000  23116   5092 S   0.0   0.1   0:01.32 gunicorn
 8 root      20   0  582404 338376   5836 S   0.0   1.0   0:47.97 gunicorn
10 root      20   0  582396 338304   5812 S   0.0   1.0   0:47.91 gunicorn
11 root      20   0  582392 338384   5796 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.17 gunicorn
12 root      20   0  582392 338204   5792 S   0.0   1.0   0:47.55 gunicorn
15 root      20   0  582392 338372   5792 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.25 gunicorn
18 root      20   0  582392 338336   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.35 gunicorn
20 root      20   0  582392 338160   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.52 gunicorn
22 root      20   0  582392 338400   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.77 gunicorn
23 root      20   0  582392 338408   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.19 gunicorn
26 root      20   0  582392 338316   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.36 gunicorn
27 root      20   0  582392 338296   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.33 gunicorn
36 root      20   0  582388 338624   6016 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.51 gunicorn
43 root      20   0  582388 338428   5800 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.34 gunicorn
48 root      20   0  582388 338460   5792 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.31 gunicorn
53 root      20   0  582388 338288   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.38 gunicorn
54 root      20   0  582388 338312   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:47.92 gunicorn
56 root      20   0  582392 338344   5796 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.14 gunicorn
57 root      20   0  582392 338360   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.07 gunicorn
63 root      20   0  582392 338312   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.27 gunicorn
68 root      20   0  582392 338384   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.46 gunicorn
75 root      20   0  582392 338312   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.01 gunicorn
76 root      20   0  582392 338344   5788 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.68 gunicorn
78 root      20   0  582392 338388   5792 S   0.0   1.0   0:47.71 gunicorn
79 root      20   0  582392 338260   5792 S   0.0   1.0   0:48.35 gunicorn
```

Gunicorn is only used by this application.
I really don't get it.

It seems that gunicorn master is spawning workers in the host as well as in the docker container?
It doesn't make sense to me.

If i'm wrong an explaination would really help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not a Linux expert, but I was curious and found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659129/docker-processes-shown-on-host-process-list), not related to `gunicorn`, but still about docker processing being shown in the host.

Basically it's intended to be that way. Docker is NOT a virtual machine, the container processes are run by the same operating system / kernel of the host and thus are visible there.

Comment: yeah that's the answer. I inspected with ps fax and indeed they are child of containers. Totally dumb question.