# ps command on host machine cannot show processes running in docker container

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, nas, synology

According to [Docker Processes Shown on Host Process List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659129/docker-processes-shown-on-host-process-list), if I run "ps" command on host machine, I should be able to see all processes running in docker container. But the actual result on my Synology NAS is different.

For example, I start the python cli in my docker container:

```sh
sh-4.2# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 14 2020, 14:45:30)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Then I run ps command in my host machine:

```sh
nas_user@my-nas:sudo ps aux | grep python
nas_user 29245  0.0  0.0  23140  2280 pts/16   S+   00:03   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

No python process is shown in host machine.

But if I start another session and connect to the container, I can see the python process:

```sh
sh-4.2# ps aux | grep python
root     12745  0.0  0.1  26560  6192 pts/6    S+   07:03   0:00 python
root     12826  0.0  0.0   9104   876 pts/7    S+   07:07   0:00 grep python
```

What's wrong with my steps? Do I misunderstand something here?

Comment: To view the processes inside the container, it is recommended that you use the following command. `docker container top ContainerName`

Comment: Are you on the same host? Is docker running containers remotely, or in a VM, in your environment? What is `$DOCKER_HOST` set to?

Comment: Another way to check for the same host: `hostname; docker run --rm --uts host busybox hostname`

Comment: The container runs on the same host. I suspect the Synology OS is a little different than the common Linux kernel. Now I'm asking in their forum.